# Intuitive way to look at $f(X_n)$ for a sequence of random variables $X_n$.

Tags: probability, soft-question, markov-chains, martingales

Let $X_n$ be a random variable, says $X_n:\Omega\to \Bbb Z$ for concreteness. Let $f:\Bbb Z\to B$ be a Borel measurable function into some Banach space $B$. What would be a good mental picture when I think about $f(X_n)$?

More specifically, I am interested in the case when $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a Markov chain or $\{f(X_n)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ a martingale.

Technically, I mean of course we can simply say that $f(X_n)$ is just a sequence of measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $B$, but it is just painful to imagine it as a function on $\Omega$ since $\Omega$ is usually implicit anyway. It seems somehow unnatural to me.

Comment: Is this a [hidden Markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)? The observations $f(X_n)$ are controlled by the "hidden" Markov chain $(X_n)$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the name hidden Markov model but I'd be interested to learn about that as well.